# How to add text in label inside gridview from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, label

I want to bind grid view from DataTable

```
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("nrtest");
    dt.Columns.Add("asd");
    dt.Columns.Add("dsa");
    dt.Columns.Add("qwe");
    dt.Columns.Add("ewq");

    dt.Rows.Add("test1","","","","");
    dt.Rows.Add("test2","","","","");
    dt.Rows.Add("test3","","","","");


    mygrid.DataSource = dt;
    mygrid.DataBind();
```

First column in my grid contains Label

I want to add first column from datatable to first column from gridview

I'm trying like this:

```
 foreach(GridViewRow gdRow in mygrid.Rows)
            {
               if (gdRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                     {
             var label1 = (Label) gdRow.Cells[1].FindControl("myLabel");
                         text1.Text = text1;

             var label2 = (Label) gdRow.Cells[1].FindControl("myLabel");
                         text2.Text = text2;

             var label3 = (Label) gdRow.Cells[1].FindControl("myLabel");
                         text3.Text = text3;
           }
      }
  but it doesn't work, at the end all the labels contain text3
```

My gridview :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="mygrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              Visible="True" width="600px" onrowcreated="GdOrarRowCreated">

          <Columns>
                      <asp:TemplateField >
                          <HeaderTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="text" runat="server" Text="text" ></asp:Label>
                          </HeaderTemplate>
                          <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabel" />
                          </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>

  <asp:BoundField DataField="asd" Visible="True"  HeaderText="col2"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="dsa" Visible="True"  HeaderText="col3"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="qwe" Visible="True"  HeaderText="col4"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ewq" Visible="True"  HeaderText="col5"/>

                       </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please post your markup for the GridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are assigning same id to all the 3 labels. Give them a unique id and then try. because it assign last value**

there are some other issues with your code though, you can try something like

```
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("nrtest");
    dt.Columns.Add("asd");
    dt.Columns.Add("dsa");
    dt.Columns.Add("qwe");
    dt.Columns.Add("ewq");

    dt.Rows.Add("test1", "", "", "", "");
    dt.Rows.Add("test2", "", "", "", "");
    dt.Rows.Add("test3", "", "", "", "");


    mygrid.DataSource = dt;
    mygrid.DataBind();
```

do stuff whatever and then to bind the grid you can use a for loop this will allow you to get the row index more easily, you can bind with rowindex then:

```
    var rows =  mygrid.Rows;
    for(int i=0,j=rows.Count; i<j;i++)
    {
        var row = rows[i];
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var label1 = (Label)row.Cells[1].FindControl("myLabel");
            //use rowindex i and colindex "nrtest" to get data from dt
            label1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["nrtest"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

The grid code will remain same as in question

```
<asp:GridView ID="mygrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visible="True"
    Width="600px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="text" runat="server" Text="text"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabel" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="asd" Visible="True" HeaderText="col2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dsa" Visible="True" HeaderText="col3" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="qwe" Visible="True" HeaderText="col4" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ewq" Visible="True" HeaderText="col5" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning same id to all the 3 lables.
Give them a unique id and then try.